# Same code but different outcomes in Google Colab and IBM Watson Studio

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, ibm-watson

I was training a simple neural network with the Fashion MNIST dataset which is directly available in the tf.keras datasets API. I trained the model in Colab and IBM Watson Studio. But I was surprised when I found that in Colab, the model was trained for 1875 gradient updates whereas in Watson Studio it was trained for 60000 gradient updates. Why no of gradient updates are different in these two environments? Shouldn't they be the same in both Colab and Watson Studio?

The code is provided here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=200)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(training_images[0])
print(training_labels[0])
print(training_images[0])

training_images  = training_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), 
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu), 
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])

model.compile(optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(training_images, training_labels, epochs=5)
```

[image: Colab]

[image: Watson]

Here are the links to [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BcAdLSeDJa4PJDqcGY9JkO76OOBGTREz?usp=sharing) and [Watson Studio](https://jp-tok.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/v2/447e056e-d14c-43fd-9e63-eed169dd1bb2/view?access_token=7d895e8561d939114ce8cceb1f9cb3837cf87ae33f8691f2a6d82bbe95e0586a).

Edit: After some more studies, I found about 'batch-size'. As 'batch-size' was not included in the code, default 'batch-size' (32) was used and thus the no 1875 (60000/32) in Colab. But I still can't understand why there are 60000 updates in Watson Studio. I will appreciate your help on this.

Comment: How many samples should there be? Which of the two has got it wrong?

Comment: @chughts There are 60000 samples. On Colab, there are 1875 gradient updates and on Watson Studio there are 60000 updates. After doing some further studies, I knew about 'batch-size'. As no 'batch-size' is mentioned here, the default value (32) is used here and thus the no 1875 (60000/32). But I can't still understand why there are 60000 updates in Watson Studio?

Comment: Should I move this question to the Data Science stack exchange?

Comment: Going by your numbers the difference seems to be that Colab is batching and Watson is not.

Comment: Yes, but why do they are handling the data differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the TensorFlow version 2.2.0, if unspecified, batch_size will default to 32.

Now, in Colab, the TensorFlow version 2.4.0 is used, and as no batch size is defined in the code, the default was used, and thus there were 60000/32 = 1875 iterations.

On the other hand, as of 30 December 2020, the TensorFlow version in IBM Watson Studio was 2.1.0 which doesn't have any default batch size. So, in that case, the dataset was not considered in batches, and thus there were 60000 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

yes the difference is both is different platform, have different computing power and have different time consumption. The no of elements/samples you are training in both is different, and that is why based on efficiency of cloud computing and computational power they are giving different outcome.

Comment: "The no of elements/samples you are training in both is different" - why are they different? As I am using the same dataset, shouldn't they be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Also the Code in watson is still running and that's why you have got only two accuracy output in watson. Let the code run completely and you will get the total 5 training output.
I guess you understand.

Comment: I have edited the question for more clarity. I am not concerned about different accuracy. Rather all I want to know is why no of training samples are different in Colab and Watson Studio?